# How to make Processing sketch keep Android screen on

Tags: android, processing

I'm trying to develop a little game for Android using Processing. It only uses sensors, and it runs fine on my smartphone, but the back lights eventually turn off and the screen locks. How can I prevent this from happening? I've tried this code, that I found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html):

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flag);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
}
```

But is says "The global variable 'activity_flag' does not exist". Deleting this line doesn't work. Any hints?

Comment: Your variable called `activity_flag` should refer to an XML layout file. Do you see that in your `layout` folder anywhere?

Comment: The only XML file I see is the AndroidManifest, there is no "layout" file. Should i create another XML file? Sorry for the ignorance...

Comment: Yes you need a layout file. It's ok to be ignorant - we've all been there at some point :-)
I think you're better off starting from scratch it sounds like. Have a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html - If I were you, I'd spent a little time getting to know the Android platform before deep-diving into more complex scenarios like this.